# Forwarding PayPal Sandbox data via GET and via cURL

Tags: php, curl, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to pass data for a paypal transaction, not with the classic form suggested by paypal, but using cURL. Could someone explain to me why the GET method works:

```
    $fields = [
            'business'          => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@business.example.com',
            'cmd'               => '_xclick',
            'return'            => 'https://www.examplemysite.com/thank_you.php',
            'cancel_return'     => 'https://www.examplemysite.com/cart.php',
            'notify_url'        => 'https://www.examplemysite.com/ipn.php',
            'rm'                => '2',
            'currency_code'     => 'EUR',
            'lc'                => 'IT',
            'cbt'               => 'Continua',
            'shipping'          => $_POST['shipping'],
            'cs'                => '1',
            'item_name'         => $_POST['item_name'],
            'amount'            => $_POST['amount'],
            'custom'            => $_POST['custom'],
            'first_name'        => $_POST['first_name'],
            'last_name'         => $_POST['last_name'],
            'address1'          => $_POST['address1'],
            'city'              => $_POST['city'],
            'state'             => $_POST['state'],
            'zip'               => $_POST['zip'],
            'note'              => $_POST['note'],
            'email'             => $_POST['email']
    ];

    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

    header('Location: https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . $fields_string);
    exit;
```

but it doesn't work when I use cURL?

```
    $fields = [
            'business'          => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@business.example.com',
            'cmd'               => '_xclick',
            'return'            => 'https://www.examplemysite.com/thank_you.php',
            'cancel_return'     => 'https://www.examplemysite.com/cart.php',
            'notify_url'        => 'https://www.examplemysite.com/ipn.php',
            'rm'                => '2',
            'currency_code'     => 'EUR',
            'lc'                => 'IT',
            'cbt'               => 'Continua',
            'shipping'          => $_POST['shipping'],
            'cs'                => '1',
            'item_name'         => $_POST['item_name'],
            'amount'            => $_POST['amount'],
            'custom'            => $_POST['custom'],
            'first_name'        => $_POST['first_name'],
            'last_name'         => $_POST['last_name'],
            'address1'          => $_POST['address1'],
            'city'              => $_POST['city'],
            'state'             => $_POST['state'],
            'zip'               => $_POST['zip'],
            'note'              => $_POST['note'],
            'email'             => $_POST['email']
    ];

    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
```

Using cURL I see, in the address bar, still the address of my site (I changed some values on purpose but the concept is that I should see the paypal url):

[www.examplemysite.com/signin?intent=checkout&ctxId=xo_ctx_XXXXXXXXXXXX&returnUri=%2Fwebapps%2Fhermes&state=%3Fflow%3D1-P%26ulReturn%3Dtrue%26token%3D4EY4066234167522P%26useraction%3Dcommit%26rm%3D2%26mfid%3D1668497487713_32d532f25ea2c%26rcache%3D2%26cookieBannerVariant%3D1%26targetService4174%3Dxorouternodeweb&locale.x=it_IT&country.x=IT&flowId=4EY4066234167522P](http://www.examplemysite.com/signin?intent=checkout&ctxId=xo_ctx_XXXXXXXXXXXX&returnUri=%2Fwebapps%2Fhermes&state=%3Fflow%3D1-P%26ulReturn%3Dtrue%26token%3D4EY4066234167522P%26useraction%3Dcommit%26rm%3D2%26mfid%3D1668497487713_32d532f25ea2c%26rcache%3D2%26cookieBannerVariant%3D1%26targetService4174%3Dxorouternodeweb&locale.x=it_IT&country.x=IT&flowId=4EY4066234167522P)

Comment: in cURL, you are using POST method. GET and POST are two different methods, which the API may or may not support both (intentionally).

Comment: @Raptor I can send the data to PayPal page, via POST via HTML form and I can also do it via GET. One doesn't exclude the other if the landing page is designed to do so. Just using cURL doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to pass data for a paypal transaction, not with the classic form suggested by paypal, but using cURL.

Nowhere does PayPal suggest doing a header redirect to `ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com` .  For checkouts, www.(sandbox.)paypal.com should be used. ipnpb is for ipn postbacks for ipn verification only, which your code is not about.

Furthermore, such a website payments standard integration cannot be done using curl. It requires redirecting the browser of an actual customer along with the transaction information (post/get fields)

To use curl or similar to set up a transaction, you need to make use of a PayPal API, such as [the current /v2/checkout/orders](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) one. Use a client id and secret to first obtain an access_token , then create the order.

Once you are able to communicate with the PayPal API successfully, the best solution is to create two routes on your server and pair them with this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

IPN is not necessary for API integrations, the capture/execution response gives an immediate notification of success or failure along with the transaction information.

Comment: In fact, you had already directed me to the new PayPal payment API V2. But honestly I didn't understand them that time. Now that I have some experience with IPN and have managed to manage the orders of my small ecommerce satisfactorily, it would probably be the case for me to update to this new version which will probably be even more secure than the others.